# USACO grader giving different response than my machine

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a USACO task and the grader outputs 4, while my machine gives 3, the correct answer.

**The input is:**

4

7 Mildred +3

4 Elsie -1

9 Mildred -1

1 Bessie +2

I have run this through a debugger and no issues were found.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int N, bmilk=7, emilk=7, mmilk=7;
int bboard=0, eboard=0, mboard=0;
int ans=0;
vector<pair<int,pair<string,int>>> a;

int main()
{
  ofstream fout("measurement.out");
  ifstream fin("measurement.in");
  fin >> N;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    int d, chg;
    string c;
    fin >> d >> c >> chg;
    a.push_back(make_pair(d,make_pair(c,chg)));
  }
  sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    if (a[i].second.first=="Bessie") bmilk+=a[i].second.second;
    else if (a[i].second.first=="Elsie") emilk+=a[i].second.second;
    else mmilk+=a[i].second.second;
    int best_milk = max(bmilk,max(emilk,mmilk));
    int curr_board[4];
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) curr_board[i]=0;
    if (bmilk==best_milk) curr_board[0]=1;
    if (emilk==best_milk) curr_board[1]=1;
    if (mmilk==best_milk) curr_board[2]=1;
    if (curr_board[0]!=bboard||curr_board[1]!=eboard||curr_board[2]!=mboard)
    {
      ans++;
      bboard=curr_board[0];
      eboard=curr_board[1];
      mboard=curr_board[2];
    }
  }
  fout << ans << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Can anybody please help me find what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read uninitialized elements of `curr_board`, and you potentially overrun it as well.

The problem is that the line intended to initialize multiple elements, instead assigns the same element over and over:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) curr_board[i]=0;
```

Reading uninitialized values is undefined behavior and could easily cause different outcomes on different machines.  Ditto for out-of-bounds access.

Why does `curr_board` have size 4 anyway?